# Recommend way to kill child process for VS Code Extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, spawn, sigkill

I have created a child process that I am trying to kill by process id.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
let child = spawn("powershell.exe", 'file1.ps1', { detached: false });
process.kill(child.pid, 'SIGINT');
```

The use of standard POSIX signals like SIGINT or SIGKILL can kill the child process but causes '**Extension host terminated unexpectedly**' error. After this none of the registered commands works for that extension. It produce "***Command 'extension.commandName' not found***" error.

Note: All the registered command is pushed in ***context.subscriptions*** and ***deactivate()*** method is also in place. I am trying it against Windows.

Comment: How about `disconnect()`?